# unable to locate credentials aws hooks

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3, airflow

am trying to create a simple DAG using airflow.hooks.S3Hook orchestrates 2 tasks the first prints a simple string on bash, the next is uploading a CSV file to AWS s3  bucket.
so I get this error:

```
                                   unable to locate credentials
```

It's a credential error related to aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key.
I know that I can solve it using boto3, but I need it with airflow.hooks

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.hooks.S3_hook import S3Hook
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

default_arguments = {'owner': 'airflow', 'start_date': days_ago(1)}


def upload_file_to_s3_bucket(filename, key, bucket_name, region_name):
    hook = S3Hook(aws_conn_id='aws_default')
    hook.create_bucket(bucket_name, region_name)
    hook.load_file(filename, key, bucket_name)



    with DAG('upload_to_aws',
     schedule_interval='@daily',
     catchup=False,
     default_args=default_arguments
     ) as dag:
          bash_task = BashOperator(task_id='bash_task',
                         bash_command='echo $TODAY',
                         env={'TODAY': '2020-11-16'})
          python_task = PythonOperator(task_id='py_task',
                             python_callable=upload_file_to_s3_bucket,
                             op_kwargs={'filename': '*******.csv',
                                        'key': 'my_s3_reasult.csv',
                                        'bucket_name': 'tutobucket',
                                        'region_name': 'us-east-1'}
                             )

bash_task >> python_task
```

Answer (score 3):

You specified an `aws_conn_id` within the `S3Hook`. This connection needs to be configured, for example via the UI, see [Managing Connections](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/connection/index.html#connection-types):

> Airflow needs to know how to connect to your environment. Information such as hostname, port, login and passwords to other systems and services is handled in the Admin->Connections section of the UI. The pipeline code you will author will reference the ‘conn_id’ of the Connection objects.

There is also a dedicated description for an [AWS connection](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/connection/aws.html):

> Configuring the Connection
>
> - Login (optional) - Specify the AWS access key ID.
> - Password (optional) - Specify the AWS secret access key.

Comment: older version of airflow where working even without this, i just upgraded to 2.0.2, and it seems to have broken the s3 logging altogether, i dont want to store keys in UI, is there any other way

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, after digging a bit I was able to make it work.

Under these fields I specified:

```
Conn Id: aws_default

Conn Type: Amazon Web Services

Extra:

 {"aws_access_key_id":"aws_access_key_id",
  "secret_access_key": "aws_secret_access_key"}
```